# Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio says "Debugging query" without doing anything

Tags: sql, sql-server

I had installed this software for doing a project with it.
But no matter how simple is the query I write, it doesn't show anything and says "Debugging query" for ever, like [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0zYTS.png)

What should I do? Thanks

Comment: What button did you click, or what key did you press, to execute this query?

Comment: Firstly, the Parse button and it said "Command(s) completed successfully.
" and after that Execute

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have confused the <kbd>`Debug`</kbd> button with <kbd>`!Execute`</kbd>.

To execute queries in SQL Server you need to use the <kbd>`! Execute`</kbd>

**Debug Button**

[image]

**Execute Button**

[image]

I dont know why this Debug button is even there, it is pretty useless in SQL Server. I normally use `PRINT` statements to see where I am in my code.